# How to add active class to codeigniter hyperlinks?

Tags: php, jquery, css, codeigniter

I know this question comes across a lot, but I just can't figure out how to do this using the, already answered posts.

I have a header with navigation links. I would like to add `class="active"` to the link that's active at the moment.

How could I do this if I have the following navigation?

```
<nav>
    <ul id="main_nav">
        <li class="home">
            <a href="search">
                <i class="icon-search"></i>
                <span>BEDRIJF ZOEKEN</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="categorie">
            <a href="categorieen/all">
                <i class="icon-list-ul"></i>
                    <span>CATEGORIE</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="aanbieding">
            <a href="aanbiedingen">
                <i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i>
                    <span>AANBIEDING</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="vacature">
            <a href="vacatures">
                <i class="icon-copy"></i>
                <span>VACATURE</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="agenda">
            <a href="agenda">
                <i class="icon-calendar"></i>
                <span>AGENDA</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="contact">
            <a href="contact">
                <i class="icon-envelope"></i>
                <span>CONTACT</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I tried this, but it did not work:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var href = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    alert(window.location.pathname)
    if (href === window.location.pathname) {
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
}); 
</script>
```

Maybe there's a better Codeigniter-ish way?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

try this one.i think no need of javascript or jquery.

If you are using codeigniter then you can use URI Class.

```
<li class="home">
    <a class="<?php if($this->uri->segment(1)=="search"){echo "active";}?>" href="<?=base_url('search')?>">
        <i class="icon-search"></i>
        <span>BEDRIJF ZOEKEN</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

please let me know if you face any problem

Comment: That works I guess, let me first look if it works for other links :D

Comment: shorter version:

`<?=($this->uri->segment(1) == "search")) ? "active" : "" ?>`

Answer (score 7):

I created a helper and saved it into the helper directory named as "menu_helper.php":

```
<?php 
if(!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

if(!function_exists('active_link')) {
  function activate_menu($controller) {
    // Getting the class instance.
    $ci = get_instance();
    // Getting the router class to actived it.
    $class = $ci->router->fetch_class();
    return ($class == $controller) ? 'active' : '';
  }
}
```

Then in config/autoload.php, I added "menu" as a helper on line 91.

The last step is to put the code for print the "active" class when accessing the page (i.e. Login Page):

```
<li class="<?php echo activate_menu('login'); ?>">    
  <?php echo anchor('login', 'Login'); ?> 
</li>
```

Comment: This deserves to be the answer, very elegant solution. Nice work!

Answer (score 0):

```
if (href === window.location.pathname) {
   $('a[href='+ href +']').addClass('active');
}
```

Comment: You can see the site here: http://kees.een-site-bouwen.nl/search I just directed to /search to see if it worked. the window.location.pathname is /search so I don't know why it isn't working.

Comment: @KeesSonnema let me check

Comment: Use `$('a[href*='+ href +']')` or `$('a[href$='+ href +']')` instead.

Comment: Good Jquery alternative then. Thanks anyway, but I'm using the codeigniter method instead :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<a class="<?=(current_url()==base_url('search')) ? 'active':''?>" href="<?=base_url('search')?>">
```