# CodeIgniter / PHP: How to get URI in .php view page

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I came across a similar issue as this user: [How to add active class to codeigniter hyperlinks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18209533/how-to-add-active-class-to-codeigniter-hyperlinks)

and the answer was to insert the following into the .php view page:

```
<a class="<?php if($this->uri->segment(1)=="search"){echo "active";}?>" href="<?=base_url('search')?>">
        <i class="icon-search"></i>
        <span>BEDRIJF ZOEKEN</span>
</a>
```

When I insert this into my page, even if my URL is "search" it does not assign the class "active" to the link tag. I tried doing this:

```
<?php 
$uri = $this->uri->segment(1);
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$uri');</script>";
?>
```

and it alerts nothing (the alert box does not display anything). I also tried alerting the following:

```
$this->uri->uri_string()
```

and I get the same result (an empty alert box). What am I missing?

Edit: My controller is Pages.php:

```
<?php
class Pages extends CI_Controller {

    public function view($page = 'home') {

        if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'/views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
        {
            // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
            show_404();
        }

        $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: what is your controller name??

Comment: @Abdulla my controller name is Pages. I will edit my page and show my controller.

Comment: post your link in question

Comment: @MeeneshJain My link? My website is on development right now (I'm running it on localhost).

Comment: Can you `vardump` your `$this->uri->segment(1)` to see what it has.

Comment: i mean to say post the complete link in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
<a class="<?php if($this->uri->segment(1)=="Pages"){echo "active";}?>" href="<?=base_url('Pages')?>">
        <i class="icon-search"></i>
        <span>BEDRIJF ZOEKEN</span>
</a>
```

`$this->uri->segment(1)` means `www.example.com/Pages/my_Method`

1. `Base URL` = `www.example.com`
2. `$this->uri->segment(1)` = `Pages`
3. `$this->uri->segment(2)` = `my_Method`

Comment: oh, okay so this worked (I just changed "Pages" to "pages" though because people generally type URL's in lower case).

Comment: @user2719875 ya. Host will be case sensitive

Comment: Host will be case sensitive? What exactly do you mean by "Host"?

Comment: host means online server

Comment: oh okay, even the localhost is case sensitive.

Comment: But localhost no harm at all. But server is not like that. I have lot experience on that kind of error. any way happy to help:

Answer (score 2):

As i have seen you are trying to apply current menu as class='active'. My sugesstion to you is that rather than finding uri and matching it. You can use following method to your controller and view.

**Controller**

`$data['active_menu'] ='search'` or

`$data['active_menu'] ='home'` or

`$data['active_menu'] ='help'`

```
   `$this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);`
```

**View Pages (Home_view.php/search_view.php/help_view.php)**

`<a class="<?php if($active_menu=="search"){echo "active";}?>" href="<?=base_url('Pages')?>">
        <i class="icon-search"></i>
        <span>BEDRIJF ZOEKEN</span>
</a>`